# Django Channels: packets sent from channel layer are not delivered

Tags: python-3.x, django-channels

I'm using channels_redis with django 1.11 (python3.6.6), and just upgraded to channels2, but none of the packets from the site are being send.

I test it with a simple view:

```
def test(request):
    send_packet(["users-{}".format(request.user.pk)], "test", dict())
    return HttpResponse("OK")

async def try_send(group, data):
    try:
        await channel_layer.group_send(group, data)
    except Exception as ex:
        debug.error("failed to send", exc_info=True)

send_packet = async_to_sync(try_send)
```

How can i debug this? There are no errors, but the message isn't delivered.

Comment: Are you getting the channel layer with `channel_layer = channels.layers.get_channel_layer()`?

Comment: I am doing that, yes

Comment: I have the same problem as you and this problem has been haunting me for several days; hopefully there will be a solution.

Comment: I dug around in channels a lot trying to solve this problem, and in my case, it seemed to be that it was opening a connection for each request it made. The newest version of channels-redis 2.3.0 helped

Comment: Also, i don't know why, but my process manager seemed to contribute. I was using uwsgi, but when i switched to supervisor, it worked better.